# Sympy: How to substitute function with function?

Tags: python, sympy

Say I have a function like this:

```
In [44]: eta(p)
Out[44]: 
                                ⎛                  Λ⋅(-F(p) + 1)    ⎞  -Λ
                1               ⎝-Λ⋅(-F(p) + 1) + ℯ              - 1⎠⋅ℯ  
1 - ───────────────────────── + ─────────────────────────────────────────
      ⎛      Λ    ⎞  -2⋅Λ                 ⎛     -Λ⎞                      
    - ⎝-Λ + ℯ  - 1⎠⋅ℯ     + 1             ⎝1 - ℯ  ⎠⋅(-F(p) + 1)
```

I would like to plot the function under some simplifying assumptions. I know that I can use `subs()` to replace the variables like `Lambda` with real numbers. That leaves me with `F(p)`.

How can I replace the sympbolic `F(p)` with an actual numerical function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lambdify()`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) and make it use numpy.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


t, omega = sy.symbols('t omega')

func = sy.sin(omega * t)

func_sub = func.subs({'omega': 2 * sy.pi})

numpy_func = sy.lambdify(t, func_sub, modules='numpy')

px = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

plt.plot(px, numpy_func(px))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the numerical function with `sympy.utilities.lambdify.implemented_function`, and use `subs` to replace.